# Aurora serverless: Unable to connect for replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm stuck trying to connect my Aurora serverless MySQL server to a Master MySQL server in the same VPC.

I checked everything to make it work, even extended the SecurityGroup from both the Master and the Aurora server to accept all connections from the VPC, still, I get a 2003 error from the Slave (Aurora):

> error connecting to master 'user_repl@vpc_ip1:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1

I even tried with the local name `ip-{local-ip-vpc}.eu-west-3.compute.internal` without any luck.

Trying to connect from another EC2 instances in the same VPC to that master, with the "user_repl" works fine, so it's not a problem of bind-address, security group on the master, passwodr or anything like that.

I wonder if Aurora serverless can replicate a master server and become slave, but if that wasn't the case, I would expect another error than just an "error connecting".

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that AWS Aurora MySQL Serverless can not do replication like we do on a MySQL server.

In order to enable replication, you'll need to use AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) where you set up a source endpoint, a target endpoint, a replication server, and enable replication between the source and the target.

I just tested it on my end and it works fine. It's a bit more work - and different than a standard replication - but it works exactly the same in the end.